# Regex: Find first occurence and map to canonical value

Tags: java, javascript, regex

I have some input data like this:

> 1996 caterpiller d6 dozer for sale (john deere and komatsu too!)

I want to match the first brand name found and map it to its canonical value.

Here's the map:

```
canonical  regex
KOMATSU    \bkomatsu\b
CAT        \bcat(erpill[ae]r)?\b
DEERE      \b(john )?deere?\b
```

I can easily test that a brand is in the string:

```
/\b(cat(erpill[ae]r)?|(john )?deere?|komatsu)\b/i.exec(...) != null
```

or what the first match was:

```
/\b(cat(erpill[ae]r)?|(john )?deere?|komatsu)\b/i.exec(...)[0]; //caterpiller
```

But is there a fast or convenient way to map the first match to the real value that I want?

```
caterpiller => CAT
```

Do I need to find the first match, then test against all patterns in the map?

I need to do 10,000+ inputs against 10,000+ brands :D

I could loop the the map, testing against the input value, but that would find the first value that appears in the map, not the input.

Comment: The way is to use the capture group number to know what is found. Basically if group m exists => CAT, if group n => KOMATSU, etc. All you need is to design your pattern to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea consists to associate the number of a capture group with an index in the canonical name array. So each different brand must have its own number:

```
var can = ['', 'KOMATSU', 'CAT', 'DEERE'];
//             ^idx1      ^idx 2 ^idx 3
var re =/\b(?:(komatsu)|(cat(?:erpill[ae]r)?)|((?:john )?deere))\b/ig;
//            ^ 1st grp ^ 2nd grp             ^ 3rd grp
var text = '1996 caterpiller d6 dozer for sale (john deere and komatsu too!)';

while ((res = re.exec(text)) !== null) {
    for (var i=1; i<4; i++) { // test each group until one is defined
        if (res[i]!= undefined) {
            console.log(can[i] + "\t" + res[0]);
            break;
        }
    }
}

// result:
// CAT      caterpiller
// DEERE    john deere
// KOMATSU  komatsu
```